# Как забиндить RadioButton к базе данных? (WPF,C#,Entity)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

Имеется база данных, где одна из колонок в одной из таблиц представляет собой переменную `Int`, которая может принимать значения (1) или (0). Значение `NULL` быть не может.

Теперь в WPF в `DataGrid`'е в нужной колонке я хочу сделать ДВЕ радиокнопки:

1. Одна из них уже нажата(та что будет соответствовать значению из БД)
2. Возможность менять свой выбор и чтобы при сохранении результатов значение в БД менялось.

Все что я смог родить на данный момент (нас интересует колонка с именем `typeColumn`):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="controllerDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,22" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                            
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="iPColumn" Binding="{Binding IP}" Header="IP" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn1" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Имя контроллера" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="typeColumn" Header="Тип контроллера" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                                        
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Type}" Tag="0" Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Type}" Tag="1" Content="Old" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="commentColumn1" Binding="{Binding Comment}" Header="Комментарий" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Можно ли решить эту задачу без применения MVVM только посредством XAML (binding)? Если же нельзя - тогда как при помощи MVVM (для работы с БД в коде использую Entity Framework)?

Comment: Вы не должны привязываться к entity-объектам. Они не предназначены для этого. Работать с базой данных в UI-потоке вообще неправильно, приложение будет виснуть.

Comment: Нене, это в коде я через EF работаю, тут же я создал объекты через data sources.

Comment: Всё равно, объекты базы не должны выставляться в UI. Я бы сделал VM-обёртку.